# node-machine-id npm library and the actual uniqueness

Tags: node.js, licensing, uuid, source-code-protection

I was testing the npm node-machine-id. It works fine to generate a "unique" machine id. However, I was hoping to get some additional advice on if this would be the best option for my needs.

In summary, I am building an electron app that will get deployed on the local station. This app will need to obtain from this machine a unique "machine id" (i should preface that i'm targeting windows x32 x64 os).

This npm info indicates says the following:

```
Win32/64 uses key MachineGuid in registry 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography (can be changed by 
administrator but with unpredictable consequences)
```

The use case for my specific scenario is needing a way to generate a true unique id for the machine. This will be used for licensing/registration purposes. I need to make sure someone can't somehow crack the licensing by essentially replicating the same unique machine id on a different station.

I want to make sure before I use a library like this npm it would actually provide the safety i'm looking for.

I also understand that in theory anything can usually be cracked with enough efforts.

So let me get to the point...

What is the best approach to obtaining a "unique machine id" in a nodejs environment? Is it possible or do i need to maybe for example write a C++ library type of external file that I can call a method via nodejs addons to get access to lower level system functions?

Thanks everyone for the review of this question.

Comment: FYI - I think that after doing some more research ... this library here https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation can be super helpful for anyone who is looking to generate a unique machine id. This library provides super extended hardware level details that can be used to string together something that would be extremely unique to the system you are using. It also has alot of methods that support Windows (good for my needs).

Answer (score 0):

The author described his/her approach very clearly, and the source code is available on Github.

Although this package will generate same 'unique' machine ID for multiple craked Windows machines as it is based on Windows registry key

> Win32/64 uses key MachineGuid in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography (can be changed by administrator but with unpredictable consequences)